# Groovy: Read and then Write to interactive process

Tags: groovy

I am beginning to think my search skills are lacking.

I trying to find any articles on how with Groovy, to open an interactive process, read its output and then write to the process depending on the output text. All I can find is how printing, reading and writing with files. Nothing about how to Write to a interactive process.

- The process is asking for a password
- Write the password to process

Something like this if possible:

```
def process = "some-command.sh".execute()
process.in.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.contains("enter password")) {
      process.out.write("myPassword")
    }
}
```

This here works reading from the process output:

```
def process = "some-command.sh".execute()
process.in.eachLine { line ->
    println line
}
```

Though it stops when the process is asking for input. It does not print out the line with the question.

Edit: Found out why it did not print the line with the ask password. It was not a new line. The question was a simple print (not println). How do I read when there is not yet a new line?

I have been told expect can be used, but I am looking for a solution which does not require a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

**1.bat**

```
@echo off
echo gogogo
set /P V=input me:
echo V=%V%
```

this script waits for input just after `:`

```
gogogo
input me:
```

this means that `eachLine` not triggered for `input me` because no `new line` after it

however the previous line `gogogo` could be caught

and following script works for `gogogo` but does not work for `input me`

**groovy**

```
def process = "1.bat".execute()
process.in.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.contains("gogogo")) {
        process.out.write("myPassword\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
        process.out.flush()
    }
}
```

**groovy2**

probably this could be optimized.. following script works without new line:

```
def process = "1.bat".execute()
def pout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def perr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

process.consumeProcessOutput(pout, perr) //starts listening threads and returns immediately
while(process.isAlive()){
    Thread.sleep(1234)
    if(pout.toString("UTF-8").endsWith("input me:")){
        process.out.write("myPassword\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
        process.out.flush()
    }
}
```